# Diff between time string and current time without year

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, difference

I want to determine the difference between a date string and the current time.
The problem is that the time string does not contain a year (But the current datetime does, so that would be make trouble on year change?)

Here's my current code:

```
date_parsed = datetime.strptime('Fri Apr 27 19:09:53', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S')
current_time = datetime.now()
```

Comment: So what is the assumed year from the string passed in, the current year? Why did you bring up the case with a year change, would the string represent a date from the previous year?

Comment: It should assume year `1900`, which you need to change.

Comment: @CoryKramer This could be. I'm analyzing a log file (tail) and when i compare a line from the previous year on e.g. a few seconds after new year this would end in a diff of 12 months if i would set the year of the formatted string to the current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assume that `date_parsed` occurred during the last 365 days, right?

In that case, use `.replace()` to change the year of that date, compare it to the current date, and adapt the year according to the result of that comparison: if the date is after now, then the parsed date should be adapted, otherwhise, it's ok:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now()
date_parsed = datetime.strptime('Fri Apr 27 14:09:53', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S').replace(year=current_time.year)

if date_parsed > current_time:
  date_parsed = date_parsed.replace(year=current_time.year - 1)

print(date_parsed, current_time, current_time - date_parsed)
```

E.g. with a date in "the past":

```
2018-04-27 14:09:53 2018-04-27 18:28:10.484371 4:18:17.484371
```

E.g. with a date in the "future":

```
2017-04-30 14:09:53 2018-04-27 18:30:48.864598 362 days, 4:20:55.864598
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it with `total_seconds` and modulo arithmetic, but then I think you have issues with things like leap years.  Probably the best way is to try two replacements:

```
tdiff = current_time - date_parsed.replace(year=current_time.year)
if tdiff.days < 0:
  tdiff = current_time - date_parsed.replace(year=current_time.year-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.strftime()` method to synchronize your `string time` and `current time` as following:

```
from datetime import datetime


date_parsed = datetime.strptime('Fri Apr 27 19:09:53', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S')
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

date_ = date_parsed.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```